# jstree delete_node() is not deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I've been cobbling together a function to put together a custom context menu for different nodes. Well, so far so good on getting different label to show up for clicks on folders or files, but not so much on actually deleting them.

Have a look. I had to ... do a little bit of a hacky workaround because I couldn't get the node.hasClass('jstree-open') yada yada to work right, but this is generally working up to the bit that's supposed to do the deleting

```
function customMenu(node) {
            //Show a different label for renaming files and folders
            var ID = $(node).attr('id');
            if (ID == "j1_1") {
                return items = {}; //no context menu for the root
            }
            var $mynode = $('#' + ID);
            var renameLabel;
            var deleteLabel;
            var folder = false;
            if ($mynode.hasClass("jstree-closed") || $mynode.hasClass("jstree-open")) { //If node is a folder
                renameLabel = "Rename Folder";
                deleteLabel = "Delete Folder";
                folder = true;
            }
            else {
                renameLabel = "Rename File";
                deleteLabel = "Delete File";
            }
            var items = {
                "rename" : {
                    "label" : renameLabel, 
                    "action": function (obj) {
                         //nothing here yet.
                    }
                },
                "delete" : {
                    "label" : deleteLabel,
                    "action": function (obj) {
                        //tree.delete_node($(node));
                        //this.remove(obj);
                        //$('#treeView').jstree('remove', $(node));
                        //nothing is working.
                    }
                }
            };

            return items;
        }
```

I've put together a fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/dpzy8xjb/
I don't think it really needs to be said that I'm not super experienced with jQuery or dealing with third party APIs, so... Be gentle.

Comment: Lots of fun to be had with JSTree. I was using AJAX to load nodes as they were needed. I found the easiest solution to deletion was to make an AJAX call to delete the node on the server, then use the callback to refresh the parent node in JSTree if the deletion had succeeded. This ensures synchronisation between my tree and the raw data on the server.

Comment: You sir, @HoboSapiens are handy. So it happens that this jstree also loads its data dynamically using AJAX; I was planning on making an AJAX call to delete the file/folder on the server if the user confirmed delete, then deleting the node on the front end but that solution sounds a lot less crappy than what I had in mind!! Heh.

Comment: @takiMartillo, Please do upvote if it helped you.

Comment: @Janty I don't know about this site in particular, but it's a pretty universally accepted concept that You don't beg people for upvotes.

Comment: You are right :))...@takiMartillo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swear to god there is nothing that drives me to figure out a problem faster than posting it on StackOverflow.

Fixed:

```
       "delete": {
            "label": deleteLabel,
                "action": function (obj) {
                //tree.delete_node($(node));
                tree.delete_node($mynode); //<<--works.
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I got that man, my solutions also works. I'm trying to get you to explain exactly what it was that you did there.

Comment: What you did set for $mynode? I mean its value?

Comment: See my edit in answer. You are finding the id and again its object. the two lines are same as if passed only node.

Comment: Well, I did that because when I was just saying $(node).hasClass(...)... it was NOT working. maybe if I just use [node] instead. I'll give it a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

DO use `tree.delete_node([node]);` for delete.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpzy8xjb/3/)

**Edit:**

The code you did is same as the `node`.

```
        var ID = $(node).attr('id');
        var $mynode = $('#' + ID);
```

Its the same object node.

Comment: so what is that `[node]` business you're using? I never seen that before. how does it differ from using the `$mynode` variable I was using?

Comment: You are using context menu for delete so its the node passed to context parameter as current node to be deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see what ya did there. I am not very familiar with the precise syntax of this plugin. Its API is not... very informative and difficult to understand in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and none of the solutions worked. And as the documentation says:

> all modifications to the tree are prevented (create, rename, move, delete). To enable them set core.check_callback to true.

In my case, I had a check_callback function (I'm using drag and drop) that was returning `false` when deleting a node.

I've adjusted it to 'delete_node' like this:

```
check_callback: function(operation, node, parent, position){
        if(operation == 'delete_node'){
            return true;
        }
        // ... rest of the code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nodes cannot be deleted unless `core.check_callback` is set to `true`.